# YouTube actionscript API

Tags: actionscript-3, youtube-api

Can anyone explain how to resize the you tube player from with actionscript3.0 code. I can get the you tube player swf to load into my application with the following code, however I am having trouble resizing the player.

```
var request = new URLRequest("http://www.youtube.com/v/_UNgokP71tw");
request.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;
youTubeLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);
Security.allowDomain("*");
youTubeLoader.load(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just change the .width & .height of the youtube object? Or am I missing something here? One gotcha may be that you need to wait until it's fully loaded before you can resize it.

Comment: Width and Height do not work for some reason, but I tried scaleX and scaleY, and they worked. Thanks for leading me in the right direction.

Comment: you cannot access .width or .height you need to use setSize(width, height)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use setSize(width, height) to change the size of youtube player.